# Node + Express + EJS link custom files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Say I have a view, and I need to use a function I wrote:

Some view's `index.js` contains this: `Today is <%= get_est_date() %>`. Trivial example...

In the same view, I include `head.ejs` with this: `<script src="/js/main.js"></script>`

main.js contains this:

```
function get_est_date() {
    return new Date();
}
```

***The rendered view, tells me `get_est_date` is undefined! I've been looking for 2 hours how to include custom js files, but no luck!***

My directory structure:

```
├───node_modules
│   ├───ejs
│   │   .........
│   └───express
│       ├───lib
│       │   ├───middleware
│       │   └───router
│       └───node_modules
│           ............
├───partials
├───public
│   ├───css
│   ├───fonts
│   └───js
├───views
│   ....
server.js
routes.js
```

server.js has this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

routes.js

```
module.exports.routing = function(app) {

  // Index
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { 
      title: "test", 
      session: req.session
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: Where is the code for rendering the view?

Comment: @elclanrs Attached routes

Comment: You didn't pass the data to the view, unless I'm missing something, it is not automatic. If you want `get_est_date` to be available you have to pass it to the view.

Comment: @elclanrs What if you want to include bootstrap.js, I have to pass 1000+ functions around?

Comment: I think you are mixing up things, the data you pass to the view from the server and the data available in the global scope in the front end are different things. By the time you include Bootstrap the view has already been rendered.

Comment: That was a bad example, I just wanted to have my own javascript library for a project. There is a severe lack of documentation for node/ejs/express.

Comment: You just include the library like `var lib=require('lib')` and pass whatever in the view `res.render('index', {lib: lib})`. The libraries you include in the HTML are not available in the server, and vice-versa; they are isolated environments.

Comment: Isn't that for npm modules? I just have a simple js file outside of modules dir that I want to include. I tried several different paths already.

Comment: You are using Node, modules are just files, you can include any file that has JavaScript code in it. `var file=require('./file.js')`. You can use relative paths.

Comment: Your <script src="/js/main.js"></script> should include relative path from server. Otherwise in a sever environment, it will not get the main.js file. Also, your Today is <%= get_est_date() %> code should be like Today is  <script type='text/javascript'>get_est_date()</script>.